# I need to send an Email notification in my exception message using asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, sendmail

I need to send and Email when Any Message occurs I am trying to logg the errors once I logged it I need to send the Email to them..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compbination of ELMAH and System.Net.Mail...

ELMAH:

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

System.Net.Mail Namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx

In Code:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
// ...
SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();
mailClient.Send(from, to, subject, body);
```

In Web.Config:

```
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
      <smtp from=your_email@gmail.com>
         <network host="smtp.gmail.com"
                  password="your_pwd"
                  port="587"
            userName="your_username@gmail.com"/>
      </smtp>
   </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: what do I need use to send an Email to Gmail   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
   client.Send(message);? I mean to say Host? and port?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) as your infrastructure of logging and in the config add an email appender ([EventLogAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)).